# Unable to call a service from host machine's IP hosted on docker container

Tags: docker

I have installed docker for windows version 3.1.0(51484) and setup a container running a memcache service on it using WSL2.

'''docker run -it -d --privileged --restart always -p 11212:11211 platform/centos/memcached /usr/sbin/init'''

I'm able to call memcache from localhost (127.0.0.1) but not from my machine's IP.

Any clue?

Comment: Examples of what you've tried to connect to the service (not just running the container) would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be about the IP setting. To check it try to listen to connection to a random port

terminal 1

```
nc -l 29123
```

terminal 2

```
nc localhost 29123
hello there
```

terminal 3

```
nc -vv -l 0.0.0.0 29124
```

terminal 4

```
nc <your-ip> 29124
hello there
```

if "hello there" appears in terminal 1, but not in terminal 3, so the problem is probably your IP/internet settings

---

Are you sure that your machine IP constant (not change)?

---

Does "Machine IP" means your "Host public IP" or "Host network IP"?

Comment: Sorry but no, Where you run this command as I run this on my windows host machine and container which is running centos7